# Mailchimp API for Rails - list.subscribe(:double_optin => false) not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, mailchimp

I am using the mailchimp-api gem and can get the submitted email to work by submitting an email and having a confirmation email sent to that email that signed up but I want to disable the double_optin flag. I am trying to do it with:

```
@mc = Mailchimp::API.new('my api key here')
@mc.list.subscribe('list_id', {'email' => params[:email]}, :double_optin => false)
```

This is still sending a confirmation email to that email address.

I really don't like how it redirects to a mailchimp page to have you confirm your subscription and have to click another button to be redirected to the site. If you could customize the confirmation email that would be one thing but having this generic confirmation page is terrible.

I am wondering if you have to have a paid account to be able to toggle the :double_optin flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up getting this to work with the following:

```
@mc = Mailchimp::API.new('my api key here')
@mc.list.subscribe({:id => 'list_id', :email => {:email => params[:email]}, :double_optin => false})
```

Note the difference here is that every parameter in `@mc.list.subscribe` is in a hash.

Comment: This is not working, generates this error "wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2..8)"

Answer (score 3):

This is what I used from [mailchimp-api](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mailchimp-api/2.0.4/Mailchimp/Lists#subscribe-instance_method)

> subscribe(id, email, merge_vars = nil, email_type = 'html', double_optin = true, update_existing = false, replace_interests = true, send_welcome = false) ⇒ Hash

The `double_optin` is the parameter which will be passed

So, I used:

```
client.lists.subscribe(@list_id, email, nil, 'html', false)
```

Answer (score 2):

This just expands on the answer from @Jordan above to explain why that works and why the accepted answer is incorrect.

If you are using the `mailchimp-api` gem, you can see in the [documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mailchimp-api/2.0.4/Mailchimp%2FLists:subscribe) that the format for a single subscribe is `subscribe(id, email, merge_vars = nil, email_type = 'html', double_optin = true, update_existing = false, replace_interests = true, send_welcome = false)`. After a lot of guessing and testing, I figured out that they don't want you to pass the parameter *names*, just the values. So, while I was originally passing `double_optin: false` in the function, they really just want you to pass `false` as the 5th parameter. In other words, this is what worked for me:

```
mailchimp = Mailchimp::API.new('mailchimp_api_key')
subscribe = mailchimp.lists.subscribe(
  'list_ID_number',
  { email: user.email },
  { fname: user.first_name, lname: user.last_name },
  'html',
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false
)
```

Note that the second and third parameters (email and merge_vars) were passed as hashes because that's how those parameters are defined in the documentation referenced above.

After making that change (removing the parameter names), subscriptions went right through without the confirmation emails.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer using `subscribe` method does not work and will still send the confirmation email, but it is easy to do this using the `batch_subscribe` method instead.

First, create an array containing a hash for each subscriber you want to add (or just one), like this:

```
subscribers = [{ "EMAIL" => { "email" => user.email},
                 :EMAIL_TYPE => 'html',
                 :merge_vars => { "NAME" => user.name
                                }
              }]
```

Then, use batch_subscribe method, like this:

```
mailchimp = Mailchimp::API.new(MAILCHIMP_API_KEY)
mailchimp.lists.batch_subscribe(MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID, subscribers, false, false, false)
```

The three "falses" at the end refer to, in order: double_optin, update_existing, and replace_interests. You can set those to true or false, but double_optin needs to be "false" if you want to skip sending the confirmation email.

Here is the [documentation for the batch_subscribe](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mailchimp-api/2.0.4/Mailchimp/Lists#batch_subscribe-instance_method) method.

Answer (score 0):

After going through mailchimp-api gem I found this solution

```
@mc.list.subscribe('list_id', { email: params[:email] }, nil, double_optin = false)
```